# Openlayers 3 - how to keep features from disappear when outside of visible view?

Tags: openlayers

I have gps coords features on a map and I want to add a line that shows the route of the feature , so I created an icon with long arrow (40px X 600px)
I've noticed that the moment I pan the map and the feature is outside of the visible area , it disappears (although the icon should still be visible)

How can I keep the features from disappear outside the visible map ?

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't it a question of loading strategy ? We usually use a bbox strategy to load only the features that are within bbox extent, but it's possible to change that to load all features. Check the doc here : http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.loadingstrategy.html

Comment: Maybe my solution is wrong , I want to draw a line to show the prediction of object advancement even when its outside of the visible area

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ol.layer.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) has a property called `renderBuffer`. This property will prevent the icons from disappearing if you set this to the pixel value of the longest side of your icon images, 600px in your example:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  renderBuffer: 600 // value in pixels
});
```

Demo code: https://plnkr.co/edit/R4qs5cmgEdYQCSu9c3gn -- Try changing the `renderBuffer` value in script.js, line 44 to see the result.

Comment: I will try this only later the week , but it looks like its suppose to work. thank you.

Comment: Will this affect the performance in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not a correct solution, but setting `useSpatialIndex` to `false` on a [VectorSource](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html) seems to allow a custom `Style.renderer` function to avoid disappearing when the feature geometry is out of view.

Disabling `useSpatialIndex` has ramifications (see the [VectorSource](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html) docs), so it's best to use in a limited way.

Perhaps another method is to do something similar to the [Graticule](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v7.1.0/src/ol/layer/Graticule.js#L470-L476) implementation, with a custom loader function.